# phpseclib 2.0 on CodeIgniter without composer, error about ParagonIE

Tags: php, codeigniter, composer-php, phpseclib

I am trying to integrate phpseclib 2.0 with my app for compatibility with PHP7.0. I previously had phpseclib working with PHP5 but a bunch of errors on my PHP7.0 machine prompted the update of phpseclib.

I am trying to not use composer completely as I do not want to depend on people to have Composer installed, so I have ran a local `php composer.phar dump-autoload -o` on my composer.json from phpseclib to generate the required autoload.php and uploaded that to my webserver.

Here is my file setup:

```
/application
 /config
 /controllers
 /core
 /errors
 /helpers
 /hooks
 /language
 /logs
 /models
 /third_party
  /phpseclib
   <phpseclib2.0 files here>
  /vendor
   /composer
   /autoload_*.php
   /ClassLoader.php
   autoload.php
```

In one of my models in which I need SSH2 and SFTP I have the following:

```
public function __construct() {
    require_once(APPPATH . '/third_party/vendor/autoload.php');
    $loader = new \Composer\Autoload\ClassLoader();
    $loader->addPsr4('phpseclib\\', __DIR__ . '/third_party/phpseclib');
    $loader->register();

    // Note $ip, $port, $user, $pass called from a config file separately.
    $this->ssh_conn = new \phpseclib\Net\SSH2($ip, $port);
    $this->sftp_conn = new \phpseclib\Net\SFTP($ip, $port);
    $this->ssh_conn->login($user, $pass);
```

Loading the page gives me an error:

```
Type: Error

Message: Class 'ParagonIE\ConstantTime\Hex' not found

Filename: /var/www/public_html/application/third_party/phpseclib/Math/BigInteger/Engines/PHP.php

Line Number: 114
```

Backtrace:

File: /var/www/public_html/application/third_party/phpseclib/Math/BigInteger/Engines/Engine.php
Line: 127
Function: initialize

File: /var/www/public_html/application/third_party/phpseclib/Math/BigInteger/Engines/PHP.php
Line: 92
Function: __construct

File: /var/www/public_html/application/third_party/phpseclib/Math/BigInteger.php
Line: 151
Function: __construct

File: /var/www/public_html/application/third_party/phpseclib/Net/SSH2.php
Line: 1670
Function: __construct

File: /var/www/public_html/application/third_party/phpseclib/Net/SSH2.php
Line: 1248
Function: key_exchange

File: /var/www/public_html/application/third_party/phpseclib/Net/SSH2.php
Line: 2126
Function: connect

File: /var/www/public_html/application/third_party/phpseclib/Net/SSH2.php
Line: 2110
Function: call_user_func_array

Any assistance is appreciated.

Comment: Did you upload the changes in the vendor folder?

Comment: What do you mean upload changes, after I ran `php composer.phar dump-autoload -o` locally? If so, yes. If not, then I do not know what you mean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you're using the master branch of phpseclib - not the 2.0 branch.

The latest 2.0 release does not utilize ParagoneIE\ConstantTime\Hex. At the very least it's not the in the composer.json:

https://github.com/phpseclib/phpseclib/blob/2.0.6/composer.json

paragonie/constant_time_encoding is, however, in the master branch's composer.json:

https://github.com/phpseclib/phpseclib/blob/master/composer.json

Comment: Ah, this could very well be it. I just copied over the files I had.Oops.